# How do I include drag-and-drop in a plugin?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I want to build a WordPress plugin that will allow users to add and delete fields from a custom post type. I want them to be able to do this with drag-and-drop, just like they add widgets to a sidebar. That is to say, the plugin will have a group of allowable fields, and the users will drag and drop those fields into a box to allow them to configure the fields in a custom post type.

Are there WordPress functions that allow developers to do this? Is there a tutorial anywhere that shows how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has a few of these libraries that come with core, you can view the list here: [Default Scripts Included and Registered by WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress). What you're looking for is [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/), and in your case [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/).

You would use `wp_enqueue_script()` to add it like so:

`wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-droppable' );`

WordPress registers these scripts using a Handle which you can use to add them, the list of Script Handles can be found in the first link above. You would still need to hook into the [admin panel and add the script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts):

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-droppable' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```